# A Graphics3D bug in version 11.1.0

Tags: bugs, graphics3d, windows, rendering

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0 and fixed in 11.1.1**

---

When an opacity option is added to 3D graphics, the axis labels go wrong, in such a way that the notebook's background colour (which can be user-defined) is used as the background colour of the label text, as shown below.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> RGBColor[0.058, 0.215, 0.262]]; 
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Cylinder[]}, Axes -> True, Background -> White]
```

It seems that the background colour of the whole graphics is not transferred to that of the labels.

[image: erroneous label background colour]

```
In[1]:= $Version
Out[1]= 11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)
```

Operating system: Windows 7.

(To change the background colour of notebooks, one can go to the Options Inspector: 
*Options Inspector -> Notebooks Options -> Display Options -> Background : RGBColor[0.058, 0.215, 0.262]*)

In addition, what options can be added to the plot to serve as a temporary fix of it?

Comment: Please do not use [tag:bugs] until it is a confirmed bug. How is that background specified exactly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on OS X, 11.1.0.  With problems like this, be sure to always add *full* version and OS information within the post itself (not comments).  Please also choose a descriptive title.

Comment: I can reproduce it on V11.1 Win10 and not on V11.0.1 so something changed. Maybe some style settings (it may be tricky to detect from where 3d graphics ticks labels are inheriting from) or it is a bug, I'd try to contact WRI Support.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the confirmation. Indeed I found it tricky: I tried changing the background colour of the labels (`LabelStyle -> Background -> Red`), only to see that that was not the background in question.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64. Probably it depends on the graphics hardware installed.

Comment: Did you change anything else than the notebook background?  Are you using the default stylesheet?

Comment: @Alexey Thanks for the information. Please add `Background->White` to the `Graphics3D` function and try again.

Comment: Yes, with `Background->White` I reproduce the bug with version 11.1.0: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Background -> RGBColor[0.058, 0.215, 0.262]]; Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Cylinder[]}, 
 Axes -> True, Background -> White]`. In version 11.0.1 the bug is absent. Please report it to the tech support.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it on OS X.  BTW please include the full value of `$Version` in your post.

Comment: Potentially related `Graphics3D` bug introduced in 11.1 on Windows: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1037168

Comment: OK here, too, with `Background -> White` in Mathematica 11.1.0 under macOS 10.12.4.

Comment: Fixed in version 11.1.1.

Comment: @Alexey Great news! Thanks!