# Label background colour in BarChart3D

Tags: charts

With the vertical axis on the front face the labels don't follow the background colour.  Any suggestions how to fix this?

Using the default `AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}}}` colours work properly.

```
BarChart3D[{{100, 200, 300}, {100, 300, 200}},
 Background -> Blue, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, 0}, None, {-1, -1}},
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 1, 0}, {None, Automatic}}, {{-1, 0, 0}, {None, Automatic}}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 24, FontColor -> White}]
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the same problem: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140437/5478

Comment: @Kuba Looks like it.  Works ok in Mathematica 11.0